# Why is my middleware not setting request attributes on logout?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I have a piece of code that sets a request attribute when the user is visiting via my `android` subdomain (shown below as part of `home.devices.py`. This is then picked up in `base.html` and used to include my `android-navbar.html`. This works fine on all of my pages except for `logout.html`. This is the case whether or not the user is logged in.

As you can see in the template snippet from `base.html` below I'm outputting the values for UA and subdomain to the page and this works correctly for all other pages, but returns nothing on the logout page.

I've also checked by adding an `assert False` statement which fires if my `request.subdomain` attribute isn't set to `android`. It isn't being triggered though, so clearly the middleware is working but the subdomain and UA variables aren't being accessed from my logout page.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Possibly relevant bits of code:

app.views

```
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    if not request.subdomain == 'android':
        assert False
    return render_to_response('registration/logout.html')
```

app.settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'home.device.MobileMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

base.html template snippet

```
    ...
    {% if request.subdomain == 'android' %}
        {% include 'home/android-navbar.html' %} 
    {% else %}      
        {% include 'home/navbar.html' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div>UA is: {{ request.ua_full }}</div>
    <div>Subdomain is: {{ request.subdomain }}</div> 
    ....
```

home.devices.py

```
# list of mobile User Agents
mobile_uas = [
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-'
    ]

mobile_ua_hints = [ 'SymbianOS', 'Opera Mini', 'iPhone', 'Mobile Safari' ]


def is_mobile(request):
    ''' Super simple device detection, returns True for mobile devices '''

    mobile_browser = False
    ua = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].lower()[0:4]
    ua_full = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    if (ua in mobile_uas):
        mobile_browser = True
    else:
        for hint in mobile_ua_hints:
            if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].find(hint) > 0:
                mobile_browser = True

    return mobile_browser


def get_ua(request):
    ''' Return the name of the user agent ''' 
    ua_full = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

    return ua_full


def get_subdomain(request):
    subdomain = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[0]
    return subdomain


class MobileMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):    
        pass

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.mobile = is_mobile(request)
        request.ua_full = get_ua(request)
        request.subdomain = get_subdomain(request)
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using a RequestContext when rendering the template, so the request variable is not present. Use the `render` shortcut instead.

```
 return render(request, 'registration/logout.html')
```